# Writing a function that returns strongest correlation

Tags: python, pandas

I want to write a function that will get the strongest correlation (highest absolute value) and return the column name. I have tried below but when I run the function I get a TypeError pointing to cor_dict[column]= abs(df[col].corr(df[column]))

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Sample': ['Sample 1', 'Sample 2', 'Sample 3', 'Sample 4'], 'Variable 1': [1,3,3,2], 'Variable 2': [3,0,3,1], 'Variable 3': [1,3,3,3]})

def find_highest_correlated(df, col): 
    cor_dict = {}
    for column in df:
        cor_dict[column]= abs(df[col].corr(df[column]))
    return max(cor_dict, key=cor_dict.get)


find_highest_correlated(df1, 'Variable 1')
```

How do I fix the Type Error?

Comment: "but when I run the function I get a TypeError" Okay, so what happened when you tried reading that whole error message, and relating it to the code? For example, do you understand which line of code it's talking about? Do you understand what it's telling you about the types of the variables there? Do you understand what the types should be? Does the error make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Let's use [`corrwith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html#pandas-dataframe-corrwith):

```
def find_highest_correlated(df, col):
    return df[df.columns.difference([col])].corrwith(df[col]).abs().idxmax()
```

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Sample': ['Sample 1', 'Sample 2', 'Sample 3', 'Sample 4'],
                    'Variable 1': [1, 3, 3, 2], 'Variable 2': [3, 0, 3, 1],
                    'Variable 3': [1, 3, 3, 3]})

print(find_highest_correlated(df1, 'Variable 1'))
# Output Is "Variable 3"
```

---

Explanation:

1. [`corrwith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html#pandas-dataframe-corrwith)

> Pairwise correlation is computed between rows or columns of DataFrame with rows or columns of Series or DataFrame. DataFrames are first aligned along both axes before computing the correlations.

2. `df.columns.difference([col])` is used to exclude the current column. [`Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) will return the columns that are not `col`. Why do we need to exclude `col`? `col` will always have the highest correlation with itself so we must exclude it if we don't always want to get `col` back.

The return of:

```
df[df.columns.difference([col])].corrwith(df[col])
```

Is:

```
Variable 2   -0.406181
Variable 3    0.870388
dtype: float64
```

3. Now we take the [`Series.abs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) of these to get the absolute numerical values:

```
Variable 2    0.406181
Variable 3    0.870388
dtype: float64
```

4. [`Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) returns the index of the maximum value. In this case, `0.870388` is the highest value and the corresponding index is `Variable 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight change from previous answer, using only `pandas.DataFrame.corr()` and a set operation to select the desired columns:

```
def find_highest_correlated(df, col): 
  corrm = df.corr()[col] 
  vrs=set(corrm.index).difference([col]) 
  return corrm[vrs].abs().idxmax()
```